# Styling the element of a list item

Tags: html, css

I am not new to CSS but i have being trying to figure out what is wrong in my Style Sheet.
I have styled the li elements of my ul but the last item is always out of line. What I want is for the `<li>` items to autofill the div width with no padding or out-of-line content. Changing my icon sizes has no effect. Please help me out

```css
ul {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 0;
  background: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

ul li a .icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
}

ul li a .icon .fa {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #F60;
}
```

```html
<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="foo">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /header -->

  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Welcome to Home</p>
    <p>Click here to go to <a href="#bar">Category</a> Page</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /content -->

  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="background-color:transparent; border:none" class="">
    <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="d" class="ui-table">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#foo" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true" class="ui-btn-active"></i></div>
            <div class="name" data-text="Home">Home</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#bar">
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="name" data-text="Category">Category</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="name" data-text="Call">Call</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="name" data-text="Chat">Chat</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="name" data-text="Help">Help</div>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
  </div>

</div>
```

I dont know how to add images here I would screen shot the display.
The display was okay but the last item is always out of line with the other items. I can't figure out how to fix this

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bc7zgdfe/ I copied and pasted your CSS and copied your html list. Perhaps you can explain the problem or expand on it to show what's going on as it looks fine to me, although I don't know if I can link font awesome

Comment: This is actually a Mobile app build using JQuery framework. I tried to build a bottom navbar with five items but the last item is always not in line with other first four items. it is displaying a little below the line of the others. Is there a way I can add Image here please?

Comment: Otherwise I would like to know if there is a way to make the items to fill out the container div. Currently, if I remove the last item, the others don't get resized, they just maintain sizes and position

Comment: There should be a button in the editor to upload an image. My guess is that the font awesome icon you're using isn't the same shape as the others, some are not square. Also the behaviour of `<li>` elements and their sizing is a bit weird, I would research this because the padding and stuff doesn't work how you'd expect when the contents grow too big. You can use `flex-grow` to make items auto-fill.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `ul` to `width: 100%` and add `flex: 1` to your `li` elements.

[flex property on MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex)